# Delete comments codeigniter with ID and user

Tags: codeigniter

how to delete comments with codeigniter, remove users based post_id ??
example :

i want delete comment (tester2) with user(admin) post_id (1)

this tables my database

```html
<table width="540" height="66" border="1" >
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><strong>post_id</strong></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><strong>id_alat</strong></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><strong>user</strong></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><strong>namaalat</strong></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><strong>commnet</strong></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><strong>input_date</strong></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">1</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">001</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">admin</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">alat1</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">tester1</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">08/09/2015</div></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><div align="center">2</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">002</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">admin</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">alat2</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">tester2</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">08/09/2015</div></td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: on which action you want to delete??

Comment: @Niranjan  yes I want deleting , if there are bad comments . in the form tool

Comment: then you should add a delete button and on click of that, execute a query and delete the comments

Comment: @Niranjan I have to do to add the delete button , but delete all the comment I wanted based on user and post_id

Comment: you want to delete both on user id and post id??

Comment: yes i want to delete post_id = 1 , with user = admin , such as in the table. how to create control and model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View,

```
<table width="540" height="66" border="1" >
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><strong>post_id</strong></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><strong>id_alat</strong></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><strong>user</strong></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><strong>namaalat</strong></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><strong>commnet</strong></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><strong>input_date</strong></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><strong>Action</strong></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">1</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">001</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">admin</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">alat1</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">tester1</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">08/09/2015</div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><a href="controller_name/controller_function?id=1&user=admin"><button>Delete</button></a></div></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><div align="center">2</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">002</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">admin</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">alat2</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">tester2</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">08/09/2015</div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><a href="controller_name/controller_function?id=2&user=admin"><button>Delete</button></a></div></td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

at Controller,

```
public function controller_function(){
   $id= $_GET['id'];
   $user = $_GET['user'];
   if($user == "admin"){
     $this->load->model('model_name/model_function');
     $data = $this->model_function->delete_comment($id);
     if(data == true){
       echo "Deleted Successfully";
     }
   }
}
```

At model,

```
public function delete_comment($id){
  $this->db->where('post_id',$id);
  $sql = $this->db->delete('Your_Comment_Table_Name');
  ($sql)? return TRUE : return False;
}
```

I hope this will help you